# Add new row by list if element not existing and duplicate part of existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have one Dataframe which has four columns: `lon, lat, datetime, others`. Regarding the last two columns, some rows are initialized with value and some are NaN.

Then, I generate a datetime list that includes date sublists, whose element number >= existing datetime for each location.

The goal is to add a new row for each new date of location, but don't copy other columns, like `others`.

Here's an example:

```
# create DataFrame
d = {'lon': [100, 100, 120], 'lat': [50, 50, 60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=['datetime', 'others'])])

df.loc[0, 'datetime'] = '2000-09-09'
df.loc[1, 'datetime'] = '1999-09-09'
df.loc[0, 'others'] = 'notes1'
df.loc[1, 'others'] = 'notes2'

# datetime element is same for same location (lon, lat)
# because we have two location, I make two sublists for each location
datetimes = [['2023-05-17', '2023-05-02', '2023-04-28', '2000-09-09', '1999-09-09'],
             ['2023-06-01'],
             ]
```

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
lon     lat     datetime    others
100.0   50.0    2000-09-09  notes1
100.0   50.0    1999-09-09  notes2
120.0   60.0    NaN NaN
```

For the first location (lon=100, lat=50), I have three new dates, and the second location has one new date.

The result should be

```
lon     lat     datetime    others
100.0   50.0    2023-05-17  NaN
100.0   50.0    2023-05-02  NaN
100.0   50.0    2023-04-28  NaN
100.0   50.0    2000-09-09  notes1
100.0   50.0    1999-09-09  notes2
120.0   60.0    2023-06-01  NaN
```

I have tried to use `explode`, but it copies all existing columns.

Comment: Is it possible that datetime will be NaN, but others will not be NaN in df table? Or other fills with datetime only?
I mean is it possible that the last row in your example will be something like: 
120.0,   60.0,    NaN,   'note3'

Comment: @MaryRa No. Only when `datetime` exists, `others` column may has value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it like this, maybe it helps (it will work if only when datetime exists, others column may has value):

```
lon_lat_unique = df[['lon', 'lat']].drop_duplicates()
lon_lat_unique['datetime'] = datetimes
lon_lat_unique = lon_lat_unique.explode('datetime')
df = lon_lat_unique.merge(df[~df['datetime'].isna()], how='left')
```

[image]

Comment: The trick of `merge` is Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible option using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
fills = (
    df[["lon", "lat"]].drop_duplicates()
    .assign(datetime=datetimes).explode("datetime")
)

out = (
    pd.concat([df.dropna(subset="datetime"), fills])
        .drop_duplicates(subset=list(fills))
        .assign(datetime= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["datetime"]))
        .sort_values(by=["lon", "lat", "datetime"], ascending=[True, True, False])
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     lon   lat   datetime  others
0 100.00 50.00 2023-05-17     NaN
1 100.00 50.00 2023-05-02     NaN
2 100.00 50.00 2023-04-28     NaN
0 100.00 50.00 2000-09-09  notes1
1 100.00 50.00 1999-09-09  notes2
5 120.00 60.00 2023-06-01     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use the original order instead of sort_values? Because lon or lat is not always in ascending order.